# Determining if the active window title contains a certain string

Tags: vb.net

What would be the code to check if an active window title contains a certain string? I've tried things involving `Process.MainWindowTitle` However I couldn't get it to function properly. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please share the code that doesn't work so we can identify what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet from [vbBlogspot](http://vbtab.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-get-title-of-currently-active-window-in-vb-net.html)

The WinAPI call getting the text length of a window:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
      Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

And here is the main function being described there.

```
Private Function getActiveWindowTitle() As String
'Get the handle currenly active Window
Dim Hwnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()

Dim WndTitleLength As Integer
Dim WndTitle As String

'Get the Window title length
WndTitleLength = GetWindowTextLength(Hwnd)
WndTitle = Space(WndTitleLength + 1)

'Get the Window title
GetWindowText(Hwnd, WndTitle, WndTitleLength + 1)

Return Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(WndTitle, WndTitleLength)

End Function
```

Though this is intended to get the title of the current window, you can make some adjustments to, say, determine only the `windowtextLength`. If it equates to zero, it doesn't contain a title.

Comment: So how would I use this in order to search for a certain string?

Comment: If for example you assigned the title of the window into a varible named `strFrmTitle`. You can use `strFrmTitle.Contains("Some String")` where some string is the one you would like to search.

Comment: Ok, also, "GetForegroundWindow()" isn't declared and 'GetWindowText' also isn't declared.

Comment: Oh, please go to the link I have added above (vbBlogspot). There are still other two WinAPI calls that I didnt included in here.

Comment: Alright, code is fine, however may I ask how I would assign the window title to a varible?

Comment: Sure. example: `Dim strFrmTitle As String = getActiveWindowTitle()` NOTE: Do this preferably in the form load event.